# Error php artisan passport:install double free or corruption (out)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

An error occurred during `php artisan passport:install`. The error is as follows:

> double free or corruption (out)
>   Magick: abort due to signal 6 (SIGABRT) "Abort"...
>   Aborted (core dumped)

This is what I have tried:

```
composer update
php artisan passport:install
double free or corruption (out)
Magick: abort due to signal 6 (SIGABRT) "Abort"...
Aborted (core dumped)

composer uppdate
php artisan passport:install --force
Magick: abort due to signal 11 (SIGSEGV) "Segmentation Fault"...
Aborted (core dumped)

php artisan passport:install
```

The passport install supposed to successful to generate the key.

Comment: can you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: when I tried with `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` it seems wasn't in the stacktrace,

Comment: check the storage logs in laravel and also any error_log files in your base directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the passport was conflict with `imagick` after I was comment `imagick.ini` on `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/imagick.ini` and restart the `apache2` after that try to execute command with `php artisan passport:install` It success to generate the client key